# Accessing element in child IFrame from parent page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to access the elements of the document in the iframe from the parent document using the following code, but cannot get it to work for some reason.

Parent.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'> 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe  id="iframe1" src="iframe.html">
        </iframe>
        <script type='text/javascript'> 

            $('#iframe1').ready(function()
            {
            console.log($('#iframe1').contents().find("#testDiv").html());
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

IFrame.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Iframe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testDiv">
            Works!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

All i am getting in console log is 'undefined' instead of 'Works!'. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using load instead of ready.

```
$('#iframe1').load(function(){
    console.log($('#iframe1').contents().find("#testDiv").html());
});
```

Comment: Ok tried it. getting 'Domains, protocols and ports must match.' error. But running this code from my filesystem.

Comment: @nedR Try Firefox its much lenient when it comes to filesystem origin issues. Anyway you should really set up a server if you really want to do web dev.