# jquery: add a class to an element located in an <iframe>

Tags: jquery, iframe, toggleclass

I use the simplest code to add a new class to an element upon click:

```
$('#nav-search').on('click', function() {
    $("#nav-search-close").toggleClass('show hidden');
    return false;
});
```

The question is how do I make it work to change a class of an element within an iframe?

Comment: If the iframe is loaded from another domain the same origin policy will not allow it... is it loaded from another domain

Comment: else try `$('iframe').contents().find("#nav-search-close").toggleClass('show hidden');`

Comment: It is loaded from the same domain (it's just another page of my website).

Comment: in that case try the above code

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762421/accessing-element-in-child-iframe-from-parent-page-using-jquery