# Get element in a frame through JS in another frame

Tags: javascript, iframe

Current activity frame is id='1'

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0",id='1'>
  <iframe src="" frameborder="0",id='2'>
    <div id="pwd">ddd</div>
  </iframe>
</iframe>
```

The thing I'm trying to do here is I want to select first `iframe` inside second `iframe`, I this is the code I started with, which is not working!

```
$($x("//div[@id='2']"), window.frames[1])
```

Couldn't find the right answer, it would be great if anyone directs me to the answer or just hint me what should I do to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure....But I think its not possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762421/accessing-element-in-child-iframe-from-parent-page-using-jquery , but the iframe you're accessing must be on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers will prevent crossing the IFrame boundary in the way you described, as it's considered a security issue. The only exception, as @Teemu mentioned, is when the frames are served from exactly the same domain, port etc. - in which case the browser will relax the restrictions